# Python slimit and d3.js

Tags: javascript, python, django, d3.js

I developed some code for data visualisation using d3. It works fine but I encountered a problem trying to integrate it into my project. It's a python/django-based application in which all javascript files get minified using slimit library. The problem is that the minimalization fail when trying to minimize d3.js script. I did try to minimize both d3.js and d3.min.js with no luck. What I did find is that it can be an encoding problem according to [this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1195) thread. I tried to apply fixes suggested there but nothing has changed. I suppose slimit does it differently so that it makes no difference what we put in javascript tag, especially if it has worked without any problems as standalone script. The most obvious solution would be to provide a d3.js script with a different encoding, expected by slimit. The problem is there isn't one since the script contain invalid characters for a different encoding.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: That is a link to facebook. I fixed it for you.

Comment: Why don't you just don't use slimit for d3? It has already a minimalization done (d3.min.js)

Comment: The problem is i cannot access the mechanisms used for minimalization meaning all scripts included will be minimized using the version they use... is there any other way round this? I know this sucks.